# Interface Builder's "Simulate Interface" and "Build and Go in Xcode" menu commands

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

How does one turn the "Simulate Interface" and the "Build and Go in Xcode" menu items into something usable for iPhone development?  Right now the Simulate command brings up the Simulator with a black screen and the Build & Go gives a "No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6)." error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nest your UIView inside a UIWindow and your controls will show up.

All except UIImageViews and images placed inside buttons.